# Hosting a JWT authentication app on my server

Tags: express, nginx, jwt, passport.js

I followed following tutorial https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/ for JWT authentication. The complete code is viewable at https://gist.github.com/JonathanMH/6bd82c0954fb8f21a837ce281da4265a .

On my local machine the app runs fine but I would like to be able to deploy it on a virtual private server running Ubuntu server with NGINX.

How should my configuration for NGINX look to get it working on the server? Currently it looks like I'm running into a CORS issue or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I was able to find a solution for this. I had to add the cors npm package to my app.js file .

Then I had to change the 'api' calls to use the public ip adress of the server (in the jwt-vanilla.js of the tutorial) and as I'm using a server that is based in an OpenStack environment I also had to allow the port 3000 in OpenStack. (more details on installing cors can be seen in following video ( https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-client-setup-for-jwt-authentication )

I used following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    location /{
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
         proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

So right now I'm running nginx and on the server in the location of the app.js (port 3000) I started 'node app.js', while in the public folder I started http-server ( npm install http-server -g) which runs on 8080.

Comment: It works in all spring ouath2 client configuration. Thank you.